# How to target and remove class from a sibling element?

Tags: jquery, removeclass, parents

So if you click on the Red class it should remove the blue_on and green_on classes (if they are being used) form the Blue and Green buttons.

```
<div id="dashboard-menu">
    <div id="red" class="red_on">Red</div>
    <div id="blue" class="blue_off">Blue</div>
    <div id="green" class="green_off">Green</div>
</div>
```

My codepen, where I'm trying to replicate my problem in a smaller area:
http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/vzolu

My real code for reference

```
<div id="dashboard-menu">
    <div id="dash-btn" class="dashboard-button-on">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <span>Dashboard</span>
    </div>

    <div id="dash-btn" class="affiliate-button-off">
    <span>Affiliate Search</span>
    </div>

    <div id="dash-btn" class="wishlist-button-off">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="count">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: List of DOM traversal methods: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/. List of CSS methods: http://api.jquery.com/category/css/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass('blue_on green_on');
```

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass

However, depending on what you're trying to accomplish, a better approach might be to take advantage of multiple (space-separated) classes:

```
<div id="dashboard-menu">
    <div class="red on">Red</div>
    <div class="blue">Blue</div>
    <div class="green">Green</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(this).addClass('on').siblings().removeClass('on'); // radio-button behavior
```

Comment: @Blazemonger That is a perfect way of doing that. except it didnt work for me. it is not even giving an error

Comment: @Nikonah jQuery, by design, doesn't give you an error if you use its methods on an *empty* jQuery object. Make sure your CSS selector is valid and your jQuery object `$(...)` is non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

You could write something generic like this:

With this you don't need to create a click handler for each id's individually and probably you can just get rid of the ids and multiple handlers based on each id with redundant code.

```
    var dash = {
    menu_red: true,
    menu_blue: false,
    menu_green: false
};


$(document).ready(function () {
    // Main function
    $(function () {
        $('#dashboard-menu > div').on('click', function () {
            $(this).removeClass(this.id + "_off").addClass(this.id + "_on"); // For the clicked item remove the off class and add the on class
            dash["menu_" + this.id] = true; // set the property to true.
            $(this).siblings().removeClass(function () { //use remove class on siblings
                dash["menu_" + this.id] = false; //set the property to false
                return this.id + "_on"; //get the on class to be removed
            }).addClass(function () {

                return this.id + "_off"; //get the offclass to be removed
            });
           console.log(dash)
        });
    });
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7wcq9/)

As others mentioned if you use just one class for `on` state you could simplify a lot like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Main function
    $(function () {
        $('#dashboard-menu > div').on('click', function () {
            $(this).addClass("on");

            dash["menu_" + this.id] = true;

            $(this).siblings('.on').removeClass(function () {
                dash["menu_" + this.id] = false;
                return "on";
            });

           console.log(dash)
        });
    });
});
```

and arrange your css like this:

```
.red, .blue, .green {
    color: #ccc;
    background: #666;
}
.red.on {
    background: red;
}
.blue.on {
    background: blue;
}
.green.on {
    background: green;
}
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdauP/)

Comment: Thanks trying this out in my bigger project :)

Comment: @Leon You are welcome... :) Just tried to help you simplify, but not sure about your real impl though. With this your flag setting will also be taken care of using the removeClass() function callback you achieve two things :)

Comment: added my actual HTML to the question, trying to update your jquery now

Comment: Hi @PSL how would you rewrite this to get the class name? $(this).removeClass(this.id + "_off").addClass(this.id + "_on"); this.class returned undefined for me.

Comment: @Leon this.className but here use $(this).addClass('on')

Comment: Thanks man, your example is the one I'm actually using in my project, it's helping me get past this block. However I felt because of the way I named my question and posted the example I had to go with @Blazemonger's answer

Comment: @Leon you are welcome and no problem. Occasionaly if u find any of my answers helpful u can just give me an upvote ;)

Answer (score 1):

I simplified your code pen considerably....

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yaJxD

Heres your complete javascript, instead of all those if/then statements you had......

```
  $('.but').click(function() {
    var color = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.but').css('background','#666');
    $(this).css('background',color);
  });
```

Just change your html to .... cuz you already have the id as the color....if you're not gonna have the id as the color, just add a data-color attribute, and change 
`var color = $(this).data('color')` instead

```
<div id="dashboard-menu">
 <div id="red" class="but on">Red</div>
 <div id="blue" class="but off">Blue</div>
 <div id="green" class="but off">Green</div>
</div>
```